# How do I get the request Url from where the call was made?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a website say www.example.com(on react). It makes an API call to our APIs written in Asp.net Core.

How can I get the requested url(www.example.com) in our API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_UrlReferrer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.Request.Host.Host`

Comment: This only works if the client uses the `Host` header. 99.99% of HTTP clients probably do use it, but it isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: So which clients doesn't send it? I'd say there's no client big enough for it to be a relevant concern